# Is it possible to extract Oracle DB from Anylogic model?

Tags: oracle, anylogic

I built a JobShop model in Anylogic and now I want to generate a DB from that model, particularly Oracle DB.

I am new to the software AnyLogic. I am expecting someone to help me if we could generate a DB from the the Anylogic Model.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot natively, nor should you.

Typically, you *have* a (Oracle or else) database aand *write* into it.

This, of course, you can do via Java.